# Data Modeling for Ordering A "Package of Packages" filled with Items

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling

Imagine an ecommerce platform that works as follows:

- A `Package`, consists of a mixture of `Items` and other `Packages`.
- An `Order` consists of a mixture of `Items` and `Packages`.
- A user can select some items, and some packages to order, but can also go ahead and remove some items from a package as part of that order, this doesn't affect the original package.
- A `Package` can change in the future, but the `Order` must show what was actually ordered as part of the packages at the time.

Here is an example:

```
Package_A: [Large_Knife, Cutting_Board]
Package_B: [Cheese, Package_A]

Order_1: [Wine, Small_Knife, (Package_B - Large_Knife)]
```

Now lets say `Package_A` changes to:

```
Package_A: [Large_Knife, Cork_Screw]
```

Which means the new `Package_B` has a `Cork_Screw` instead of `Cutting_Board`.

When the user looks at his old order he should see what he actually ordered.

```
Order_1: [Wine, Small_Knife, Package_B([Cheese, Cutting_Board])]
```

There is no need to store/show that `Large_Knife` was removed if that makes it easier to model.

Would love to hear ideas on how to model this.

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't stated all your business rules.  What is the difference between ordering a `cutting-board` as a item and ordering a `cutting-board` as part of `[packge_a - (large-knife)`?  Does the e-tailer care?  Does the customer?  Does the packing / shipping department case?

Answer (score 1):

An Item can be in many Packages.

A Package can contain many Items.

An Order can have many Items and Packages.

A Package or Item can be in many Orders.

A User can place many Orders.

A Order is placed by one User.

Package's items can change over time, but there´s no need to track this changes.

If a Package changes, Orders containing that Package should not be affected, and its content should remain as it was by the time it was ordered.

Proposed Model:

User: UserId(PK), LastName, FirstName, Email

Item: ItemId(PK), Description

Package: PackageId(PK), Description

PackageDetail: PackageId(FK), ItemId(FK)

Order: OrderId(PK), UserId(FK), DateOrdered

OrderDetail: OrderId(FK), ItemId(FK, not null), PackageId(FK, "0" if it's an Item)

If the Order contains an Item, field ItemId on table OrderDetail must contain its PK, and PackageId must be set to "0".

If the Order contains a Package, containing 3 items by the time it was placed, you must insert 3 rows on table OrderDetails, all with the same PackageId but with different ItemdId.